# Do I need to do 301 redirect when changing file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently:

`www.mysite.com/index.php` displays as `www.mysite.com/index`

I've redone my site and saved all of the files as .html files. So now:

`www.mysite.com/index.html` displays as `www.mysite.com/index`

Basically, all of the **file names have stayed** the same but the **extension has changed** from .php to .html.  Before uploading the new files to the live server, should I be doing a 301 redirect of ALL the old .php URL's to the new .html URL's?

Keep in mind I have used .htaccess to not require users to enter the extension.

Comment: You could add a clause to .htaccess to redirect .php to non .php with a regex match

Comment: Confused...does "displays as" mean that the url to the *.php file is www.mysite.com/index. If so, what is the redirect for? The url stays the same, or isn't it?

Comment: @Eric Show your .htaccess -- it's much easier to answer when I see what you are talking about **exactly**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already rewriting the URL's so you don't require the `.php` extension for *any* users then you only need to change your .htaccess so that they're now rewritten to the correct `.html` extension. There's no need to inform your end users with a 301 code if nothing changes from their perspective.

But if you do have *some* users using the extension now, you will need to use a 301 redirect to inform them that the URL has changed. It is advisable to redirect `.php` filenames to the no-extension version so that going forward, it becomes a non-issue and all your users use the non-extension versions.